# Doc2Vec (Or Word2Vec) In Catalyst C#: How Do I get it to give results? (FastText)

Tags: c#, nlp, doc2vec, fasttext

I'm trying to replicate results from Gensim in C# to compare results and see if we need to bother trying to get Python to work within our broader C# context.  I have been programming in C# for about a week, am usually a Python coder.  I managed to get LDA to function and assign topics with C#, but there is no [Catalyst](https://github.com/curiosity-ai/catalyst) model (that I could find) that does Doc2Vec explicitly, but rather I need to do something with FastText as they have in their sample code:

```
// Training a new FastText word2vec embedding model is as simple as this:
var nlp = await Pipeline.ForAsync(Language.English);
var ft = new FastText(Language.English, 0, "wiki-word2vec");
ft.Data.Type = FastText.ModelType.CBow;
ft.Data.Loss = FastText.LossType.NegativeSampling;
ft.Train(nlp.Process(GetDocs()));
ft.StoreAsync();
```

The claim is that it is simple, and fair enough... but what do I do with this?  I am using my own data, a list of IDocuments, each with a label attached:

```
using (var csv = CsvDataReader.Create("Jira_Export_Combined.csv", new CsvDataReaderOptions
            {
                BufferSize = 0x20000
            }))
            {
                while (await csv.ReadAsync())
                {
                    var a = csv.GetString(1);  // issue key
                    var b = csv.GetString(14);  // the actual bug
                    // if (jira_base.Keys.ToList().Contains(a) == false)
                    if (jira.Keys.ToList().Contains(a) == false)
                    { // not already in our dictionary... too many repeats
                        if (b.Contains("{panel"))
                        {
                            // get just the details/desc/etc
                            b = b.Substring(b.IndexOf("}") + 1, b.Length - b.IndexOf("}") - 1);
                            try { b = b.Substring(0, b.IndexOf("{panel}")); }
                            catch { }
                        }
                        b = b.Replace("\r\n", "");
                        jira.Add(a, nlp.ProcessSingle(new Document(b,Language.English)));
                    }  // end if
                }  // end while loop
```

From a set of Jira Tasks and then I add labels:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IDocument> item in jira) { jira[item.Key].Labels.Add(item.Key); }
```

Then I add to a list (based on a breakdown from a topic model where I assign all docs that are at or above a threshold in that topic to the topic, jira_topics[n] where n is the topic numner, as such:

```
var training_lst = new List<IDocument>();
foreach (var doc in jira_topics[topic_num]) { training_lst.Add(jira[doc]); }
```

When I run the following code:

```
 // FastText....
 var ft = new FastText(Language.English, 0, $"vector-model-topic_{topic_num}");
 ft.Data.Type = FastText.ModelType.Skipgram;
 ft.Data.Loss = FastText.LossType.NegativeSampling;
ft.Train(training_lst);
var wtf = ft.PredictMax(training_lst[0]);
```

wtf is (null,NaN).  [hence the name]

What am I missing?  ***What else do I need to do to get [Catalyst](https://github.com/curiosity-ai/catalyst) to vectorize my data?***  I want to grab the cosine similarities between the jira tasks and some other data I have, but I can't even get the Jira data into anything resembling a vectorization I can apply to something.  Help!

**Update:**
So, Predict methods apparently only work for supervised learning in FastText (see comments below).  And the following:
`var wtf = ft.CompareDocuments(training_lst[0], training_lst[0]);`
Throws an Implementation error (and only *doesn't* work with PVDM).  **How do I use PVDM, PVDCbow in Catalyst?**

Comment: Note that the `Doc2Vec` model in Python Gensim – an implementation of the 'Paragraph Vectors' paper algorithm – is related to, but different from, other algorithms in the word2vec family, like FastText. You can't really approximate it just by feeding different training data to a `FastText` model, or doing anything different with the model's output. You'd need to change core training actions inside the library code. (You *might* be able to do this via overriding some parts, while reusing most, but that depends on the starting design.)

Comment: Matching plain word2vec in FastText is easier: turning off all subword-related features – which might be possible by setting the `min_n` & `max_n` paramters to 0, and/or the `buckets` to 0. Then, the `FastText` approach without any subword information is essentially word2vec. And at the end of training a `FastText` model, the usual operation is to ask it for individual word vectors, for either training-time-known (in-vocabulary) or previously-unseen (out-of-vocabulary or 'oov') words.

Comment: (If your attempted `PredictMax` is meant to mimic FastText's label-prediction via the `.predict()` method, that's only available in FastText models that are trained in the separate `--supervised` mode, where the original training examples were all labeled. I don't see anything in your code implying that's the kind of training you did.)

Comment: Thank You gojomo for the response(s), that makes sense as to why my ```.Predict()``` or ```.PredictMax()``` are empty/null, but I'm at a loss to figure out how to get the FastText model to spit out the actual vectorization of the document for use oin... any use really.

Comment: In its base configuration & most-common usage, `FastText` defines no vectorization of full texts. It only vectorizes individual words. If you need some sort of multi-word (setnence/paragraph/document/etc) vector, you must decide yourself how you want that to happen. Averaging all the individual words together is one common baseline approach, you can do yourself, outside the model.. (That's also what `FastText`'s `--supervised` mode does, both during training and in response to post-trainng `.get_sentence_vector()` requests. But that isn't quite what Gensim `Doc2Vec`/paragraph-vectors does.)

Comment: I am able to get something out of this: ```ft.TryGetDocumentVector(jira[doc], out var doc_vector)```, usually.  It's a bool that throws a vector into ```out var doc_vector``` when true.  The value thus far hasn't been great, but that could be for a variety of reasons.